# Polyline not showing up on Api v2 android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Anyone see why my polyline isn't drawing a line as I move? The map shows up and the position arrow is tracking, but no line is drawn. I thought this was all was needed to continually make the line track:

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
rectOptions.color(Color.RED);
mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {setIt = true;};
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) { mMap.clear();};
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPauseIt) { setIt = false;};
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonResume) { setIt = true;};

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    rectOptions.color(Color.RED);

     if (setIt == true){
          mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you continually add a new polyline with only a single point, which gives no line, try and save the rectOptions as a field variable:

```
        PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(
                Color.RED);

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            rectOptions.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

             if (setIt == true){
                  mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
             }


        }
```